# Proving/disproving general analysis statements

Tags: real-analysis

Okay, here's three statements about general real analysis, that I have to prove if it's correct or incorrect.

> a. Every isometry is continuous.
>
> b. [0,1] is not isometric to [0,2]
>
> c. Every isometry is a homeomorphism

I know a and c is true, but is b. necessarily true?  Also, even though a and c are true, how do I prove it?  Ty.

Comment: For b, what points could map to 0 and 2? $\;$

Comment: Could you give us the definitions you're using? Different authors use different ones. I mean, an isometry is often defined as a continuous map that preserves distances, so that d(a,b)=d(f(a),f(b)). And you can also talk about the existence o a metric other than the subspace metric so that the distance is preserved in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

For a) to prove that every isometry is continuous:

For $f : M → N$ to be continuous, we must show $f$ is continuous at every point of M. That is, for any $x ∈ M$ and for all $ε > 0$, there exists a δ > 0 such that $d_M(x, y) < δ$ implies $d_N(f(x), f(y)) < ε$. Fix $x∈M$ and ε > 0. Choose δ = ε. Then if $d_M(x,y)<δ$,the definition of an isometry $f$ gives $d_N(f(x), f(y)) = d_M(x, y) < δ = ε$.

We have shown that any isometry f is continuous at all points in M and therefore is continuous.

For b) to prove that $[0, 1]$ is not isometric to $[0, 2]$:

Assume the metric spaces $[0, 1]$ and $[0, 2]$ are equipped with the Euclidean metric. Suppose that there exists an isometry $f : [0, 1] → [0, 2]$ such that $d_{[0, 2]}(f(x), f(y)) = d_{[0, 1]}(x, y)$. This would imply that $|f(x) − f(y)| = |x − y|$ for $x, y ∈ [0, 1]$. Since $f$ is a bijection, it is surjective and hence there must exist $x,y ∈ [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $f(y) = 2$. Then $|f(x)−f(y)| = |−2| = 2$. Since $d(w,z) \le 1$ for all $w,z ∈ [0, 1]$, we have that $|f(x)−f(y)| = 2 > 1 \ge |x−y|$. This contradicts the assumption that $f$ is an isometry and therefore there is no isometry between $[0, 1]$ and $[0, 2]$, implying that $[0, 1] \neq [0, 2]$.

For c) to prove every isometry is a homeomorphism:

We say that $f : M → N$ is a homeomorphism if $f$ is a bijection and is continuous, and the inverse bijection $f^{−1} : N → M$ is also continuous (reference Pugh 57). From the definition of an isometry we have that an isometry $f : M → N$ is a bijection and from part a), we have shown that $f$ is continuous. Since $f$ is bijective, it has an inverse $f^{−1}$ mapping elements of N to elements of M, which may or may not be continuous. For $f^{−1}$ to be continuous, it must be continuous at every point in N. Because f is a bijection, we also have that any value $p ∈ N$ is the mapping of an element $x ∈ M$ such that $f(x) = p$.

Fix $p ∈ N$, $p = f(x)$ for some $x ∈ M$,and $ε > 0$. Choose $δ = ε$. Then for $q ∈ N$ with $q = f(y)$ for some $y ∈ M$ satisfying $d_N(f(x), f(y)) < δ$, the definition of an isometry $f$ gives $d_M(f^{−1}(f(x)), f^{−1}(f(y))) = d_M(x, y) = d_N(f(x), f(y)) < δ = ε$.

Therefore $f^{−1}$ is continuous at all points in N and therefore is continuous. Since $f^{−1}$ is continuous, we have that f satisfies the definition of a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f:[0, 1] \to [0, 2]$ is a homeomorphism.

The distance between $0$ and $2$ is $2$.

The distance between $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}(2)$ is not greater than $1$.